# Runtime assigning connection string not working

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string

I am having following scenario

```
SqlConnection  sqlMdfCon = new SqlConnection();
sqlMdfCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + txtDataSource.Text + ";Initial Catalog=" + txtDatabase.Text + ";Database=" + txtDatabase.Text + ";User ID=" + txtUserID.Text + ";Password=" + txtPassword.Text + ";Integrated Security=False";
if (sqlMdfCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    sqlMdfCon.Open();
}
dTable = sqlMdfCon.GetSchema("Tables"); 
 foreach (DataRow DRow in dTable.Rows)
 {

    if (DRow["TABLE_TYPE"].ToString() == "TABLE" || DRow["TABLE_TYPE"].ToString() == "VIEW" || DRow["TABLE_TYPE"].ToString() == "BASE TABLE")
    {
       intPos = DRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().LastIndexOf("FilterDatabase");
       lstTables.Items.Add(DRow["TABLE_NAME"]); // Getting error here
    }
 }
```

Following is the exception

```
ConnectionString property is not initialized
```

Why i am getting this even i have assigned the connection string properly to connection ?

Comment: is Initial Catalog required? I can't remember

Comment: Why are you setting both `Initial Catalog` and `Database`?  They're equivalent.

Comment: @DavidHoerster ok i will remove it, But is it the reason of getting exception ?

Comment: Possibly -- it's probably a good place to start.  Hopefully that works.  But are you getting the exception when you `Open()` the connection or when you `GetSchema`?

Comment: So I missed your comment on where you're getting the exception.  What is `lstTables`?  Where is that initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SqlConnection  sqlMdfCon = new SqlConnection(sqlMdfCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" +     txtDataSource.Text + ";Initial Catalog=" + txtDatabase.Text + ";Database=" + txtDatabase.Text + ";User ID=" + txtUserID.Text + ";Password=" + txtPassword.Text + ";Integrated Security=False";);
sqlMdfCon.Open();
dTable = sqlMdfCon.GetSchema("Tables");
```

By the way, I'd add a try/finally statement to dispose connection object properly. And I hope you're not constructing your queries the same that connection string...

Comment: Please look at the edited question. Actually getting error some where else

Comment: Same answer apply, you can provide connection string in constructor. And skip the ConnectionState check, a newly created connection will be always close. Remove the Database keyword from connection string as suggested and leave only Initial Catalog. And dispose connection object properly!